# Vuejs value before modification in watchers

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In vuejs, we are able to access the value after modification in watchers like this:

```
watch: function(valueAfterModification){
     // ......
}
```

But how do we get the value **before** modification?

PS: the documentation does not have anything about this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just have one more parameter in the watcher function to get the oldValue, Like following:

```
  watch: {
    value: function(newVal, oldVal) { 
       //oldVal is the value before modification
       alert('newVal ' + newVal + ' oldVal ' + oldVal)
    }
  }
```

See sample fiddle [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/a9amx3tf/).

Comment: Yes this works. But Is this a documented way of doing it? I mean if its there, then why is it not in vue documentation? Maybe this could break in future versions of vuejs if not documented!